# What does FD_SETSIZE mean while installing webRTC TURN server?

Tags: turn

I install a TURN server for my webrtc app, while configuring TURN server
source code, there are 3 options for me to choose:

```
--enable-debug-build                 : allow to compile with debug informations
                                   default=no
--enable-fdsetsize=number            : allow to preconfigure FD_SETSIZE macro
                                   (must be a number >=32) default=no
--enable-xor-peer-address-max=number : allow to preconfigure
                                   XOR_PEER_ADDRESS_MAX macro (must be a
                                   number > 0) default=5
```

and I do not know how to use FD_SETSIZE option? Does anyone tell me?

Comment: My advice is if you don't know what an option does, then don't use it, the default will most likely be okay.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hi, I use the default exactly.